# Flutter get reference after navigation pop

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I would like to get a reference to the screen I am going to show.

With this code:

```
Navigator.of(context).pop()
```

I actually going back to the previous screen but I would like to access that reference to do some work.

How can I do that?
With my iOS background working in Swift I would have done something like that:

```
var newScreen = Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

Comment: May i know what you want to do with the reference, because by the time you `pop`, the `BuildContext` on that route will be dead and you can't do much work then.

Comment: Sorry I changed the var name. I would like to have the new screen reference not the popped one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a reference because when you pop the current "route" all the data will be disposed.

But you can return a [pop result](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pop.html) to the awaiting parent as explained by official [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data#4-when-a-button-is-tapped-close-the-selection-screen).

Something like:

```
//When you will dispose the pushed page/route you can pass your result to pop method
Navigator.pop(context, 'This is my new page result');

//In the parent page you will await for the result
final result = await Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyPushedPage()),
  );
print(result) //--> This is my new page result
```